# handling pixels in xsl fo

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, xsl-fo

I have a Web front end and I am trying to handle layout with tables, because my tables all contain a col with a width- in pixels, what is the best way to handle it inside the pdf to get a consistent layout...?

I am using fo.net and the code I use to convert pixels to in is: However on different machines I am getting inconsistent results...

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="floor(@width div 72)"/>
              <xsl:text>in</xsl:text>
```

Is there a way using c# to get the screen resolution and any other info to get a more accurate result?

Comment: I think it's hardly possible that `floor(@width div 72)` would give _"on different machines "_ [...] _"inconsistent results"_ ...

Comment: @Alejandro: I Know the results will vary a little bit but I thought so many people may have come across this problem and found ways to resolve it for example there is a pxToEm jquery converter, what if I used em, would that work? As a work around I have set the max length of the table to be 170mm inside the xslt that is exactly the same, ok I cannot have nested tables but its cool... This way if I have 2 or 3 columns all the cols width are set by pixels no problem I will have a reasonable level of consistency across browsers, or no?

Comment: Or alternatively force/ calculate my tables so they are in %, have a fixed max width in HTML and calucalte the % inside the xslt could be another option possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question... use % with a fixed max width on the table, that way I can get the Xsl to work out the % of each column based on the total width of a table. This workaround seems like the best and most felxible way to handle my situation, the biggest problem is, pixels cannot be translated into xsl fo - if a person is working on a page then moves onto a different machine the outputted pdf could be drastically different.

On the note: I would like for mm to be supported alongside pixels in WYSIWYG editors... as I am using jquery client side I will most likely enhance my tables therefore requiring me to create this plugin. I hope this info helps anyone else who wants to create pdfs from client side WYSIWYG editors, I am sure this info can be applicable for other scenarios too... :)

Answer (score -1):

In the class 'System.Windows.Forms.Screen' there are several functions and values concerning the screen.

Comment: I have a web app... asp.net mvc2 more specifically, thanks for the info anyway...

Comment: If I could get hold of screen resolution something like this may work: mm = (pixels * 25.4) / dpi where 25.4 = 1 inch